# SQL join and repeat the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables :

```
1)participant
  ***********
  +id_participant
  +id_poste
  +name
  +email

2) profile_formaion
  ****************
  +id_poste
  +id_formation

3) formation
  *********
  +id_formation
  +lable
```

`EXAMPLE:`

DATA:participant

```
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com
```

DATA:profile_formation

```
2 | 3
2 | 4
```

DATA:formation

```
1 |lable1
2 |lable2
3 |lable3
4 |lable4
```

Anyone could help me How can I use sql statement(join) to get the result:

DATA:result

```
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com | label3
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com | label4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    participant.id_participant,
    participant.id_poste,
    participant.name,
    participant.email,
    formation.lable 
FROM participant
INNER JOIN profile_formaion ON
    profile_formaion.id_poste = participant.id_poste 
INNER JOIN formation ON
    formation.id_formation = profile_formaion.id_formation
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
select p.*, f.lable
from participant p
join profile_formaion pf on pf.id_poste = p.id_poste
join formation f on f.id_formation = pf.id_formation
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT p.`id_participant`,p.`id_poste`,p.`name`,p.`email`,f.`lable` FROM participant p join profile_formaion pf on p.id_poste = pf.id_poste join formation f on pf.id_formation = f.id_formation